# Show-hide divs with css

Tags: css, mobile, hide

I have a large section of code that has a number of differences depending on if the view is mobile or desktop. I'm trying to control which section of code displays with the code shown below. Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/axk9y3zq/14/) No matter how I adjust the widths, both div's appear. Is this possible or do I need to use javascript?

```
    <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px {
     div.is-not-mobile {display:none;}
     div.is-mobile {display:block;}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px  {
     div.is-not-mobile {display:block;}
     div.is-mobile {display:none;}
    }
    </style>

    <div class="is-not-mobile">
     <div>This is not a mobile view</div>
    </div>

    <div class="is-mobile">
     <div>This is a mobile view</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're missing two )s I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing closing parenthesis `)` in `(max-width: 600px)` and `(min-width: 600px)`.

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     div.is-not-mobile {display:none;}
     div.is-mobile {display:block;}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px)  {
     div.is-not-mobile {display:block;}
     div.is-mobile {display:none;}
    }
</style>

    <div class="is-not-mobile">
     <div>This is not a mobile view</div>
    </div>

    <div class="is-mobile">
     <div>This is a mobile view</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the given code your missing `(max-width: 600px`  parenthesis. the correct code will be (max-width: 600px)
2. Also, make sure you have meta tags in your head section
3. Best practice try to add your media queries from internal  tag to external CSS file at the end of code.

Hope this will work. Happy Coding!